# Designing Firebase Schema to Query Trending Posts

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as Backend DataBase for an Blog Site . I would like to know how can i structure my Firebase DB; Based on Which i can determine which posts is most trending recently .

Lets take the following example .

posts
   --[Post 1]
            |-PostId : Post1
              |-PostName: OLD
               |-PostLikes : 100
               |-PostCreatedTimeStamp : 1483107180599
               |-PostCreatedDate :20141204 /* Date Format in YYYYMMDD format */ 
 --[Post 2]
               |-PostId : Post2
               |-PostName: NEW
               |-PostLikes : 40
               |-PostCreatedTimeStamp : 1483115276906
               |-PostCreatedDate :20161204

As per the above example we can see that even though Post 2 had got less number of likes it is currently trending as it had got more number of likes within small period of time . 
How can we structure our Firebase based on this .

I have also find a temporary solution . By creating an Like Coefficient.
LikeCoefficient=((no of likes)*10000000)/(RecentlylikedTimeStamp- createdTimestamp).
There is bug with this approach.If A trending posts stops getting likes . There is no way i can update the coefficient. Thus old posts can come in between as well .(I don't want to use backend server :) . It will increase cost which i dont want in this stage ). 
[Question to Maths gigs:]Can we improve the LikeCoefficient to represent recent trending posts order by created timestamp.

@FireBaseteam : Why cannot we have two orderbychild params . Why team why .. :( :(

Answer (score 0):

You need a third data structure to support trending properly. Trending algorithms are almost always "exponential moving averages" (EMAs). Although it's not their only purpose, they're commonly used in stock trading and you can find the explanation and formula here:

http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_averages

Essentially what you want to do is maintain a list of scored elements. You might only have a single component to consider that makes an item "trend", such as comments being posted, in which case the score for every item is simply 1.0. But you can also do clever things like say "a top level reply is worth 1.0, and a second level reply is worth 0.5". You can include anything you want in these algorithms - comments, replies, star ratings or votes, thumbs-up, shares, etc.

Figure out how you want to weight or score those, and create code that adds those score entries to a data set when they're made. In each entry, you'll probably want to store information about the user who created it, what action was being performed, the score for that action, and the datetime (in milliseconds) it happened.

From there, you just apply the EMA formula to create an overall weighted score for each post. One really nice thing about the EMA is that, although you want to remember the list of all entries in a score for later reference, it's not necessary to query them all to adjust the EMA for each new value. The EMA can be calculated just from the data at hand, using the formula in the link above. And since EMAs preference "newer" data, they automatically indicate trending items because older items drop off.

You will need a way to maintain these values over time, typically a background/batch process that helps assist with expiring old items. Alternatively, the batch process can calculate CURRENT trending items, and post those to a `/trending-posts` collection that can be displayed immediately. This option is my personal preference, YMMV.

Comment: If you use EMA, you need to update all the EMA values on a daily basis for them to be up to date.